# Taking a screenshot of Android Emulator in background with OpenGl app

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es, screenshot, android-sdk-tools

I'm looking for a way to take a screen shot/screen capture of an openGL application that is behind another window. Namely, I want to screen capture the Android Emulator running an openGl app.

---

Since the Android Emulator is behind another window, it's not visible on the PC screen, so that taking a normal screenshot or using one of the several screenshot tools I found does not work. Making the Android Emulator the active window to capture it is not an option, because I don't want to distract the computer user.

Of the numerous screenshot tools I tried, one was able to capture background windows. But it couldn't handle opelGl and returned only a black picture. I didn't find a tool that could handle both background windows and openGl.

Note: Although the user should not be disctracted, using a graphical screenshot tool will probably work. I'd do this by leaving the tool in the background and sending it mouse/keyboard input, e.g. via AutoHotkey.

I'd also be comfortable with writing a program for this task, but I haven't found a way to screen capture an openGl window. It's possible to [capture Direct3D Windows](http://spazzarama.com/2011/03/14/c-screen-capture-and-overlays-for-direct3d-9-10-and-11-using-api-hooks/), and it is also possible to [draw the content of an openGl window somewhere else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but neither of this seems to be helpful here.

Using the android debug bridge to take a screenshot returns only black pictures. People often suggest turning the gpu acceleration of the emulator off, but when I do this, the android app I'm trying to capture doesn't start anymore.

I'm using Windows 7 (32bit) with the latest Android SDK and Android 4.4.2. When the Android Emulator is visible, a normal screenshot shows it's actual content, not only a black rectangle.

So is there any way to do what I want?